# Does `git` name only as "origin" any remote upon cloning?

Tags: git

Does Git only use the remote name "origin" for a repository which was created by cloning?

For example, say I create a repository, placed it on a remote, and try to clone it again into the same directory, which one would Git name origin?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you `init` a repository, you can't `clone` into the same place as `clone` always creates a new repository. You can add a remote called origin (if you don't already have one) with `git remote add origin <url>`, if that's what you want?

Comment: @Charles: I think there was a bit of fuzziness in "same directory" - maybe same parent directory, for example. My best guess is the actual aim of the question was whether git magically knows where the real original repository was. (And of course it doesn't, it just knows where you cloned from and calls it origin.)

Comment: With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021, 11 years later), you now have the option [`clone.defaultRemoteName`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627822/6309).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

2010: `origin` is the default name used by [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), but you can use any other name when cloning:

```
--origin <name>
-o <name>
```

> Instead of using the remote name `origin` to keep track of the upstream repository, use `<name>`.

If you don't, any time you clone a repo, that remote repo will be referenced by the default name `origin`.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021, 11 years later), you now have the option [`clone.defaultRemoteName`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627822/6309).

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand git better. I think git has too many shortcuts and abbreviated ways of doing the same thing and it all gets confusing.
To put it precisely, a git clone command which omits the --origin name or -o name options defaults to using 'origin' as a shortcut/name for that repo.

I think the git user community's eagerness to show how easy and simple git commands can be made only makes slows down comprehension

Comment: Are you saying you'd rather it ask you for the upstream name every time avoiding any hope of consistency, or just never allow you to change the name of that remote?  There's nothing special about a remote name.  I have large numbers of remotes in some of my repos.  Some have two (or more) natural upstreams.  git has very little magic.  Declaring the word `origin` magical would only make comprehension harder.

Answer (score 24):

If `origin` doesn't fit you, you can always rename it to a more appropriate name:

```
git remote rename <old> <new>
```

See description of [git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

Comment: This is way better than my stupid way... `git remote rm <old> | git remote add <new> https://...`

Comment: You can run "git branch -a" and/or "cat .git/config" to see the changes immediately.

Comment: I find it better to set the remote name when I clone. Personally, I don't like `origin` because it doesn't tell me anything meaningful. So, I usually name it according to where it comes from. E.g., if I'm cloning from a github repo, I'll do `git clone -o github git@github.com:username/repo.git`. That way, my remote is called `github` which is much more meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/40696c67274305d6258539de5a36649cf833f712/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> learned **`clone.defaultremotename`** configuration variable to customize what nickname to use to call the remote the repository was cloned from.

See [commit de9ed3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de9ed3ef3740f8227cc924e845032954d1f1b1b7), [commit 75ca390](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75ca3906b1ea6a00a20ef16c889e9d6a15a8defc), [commit ebe7e28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebe7e28a3600f4e67e9a1781e335adb36f3f139b), [commit f2c6fda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2c6fda88624370fda1fc706a0f2ceda7d50d6ab), [commit 444825c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/444825c7c1148c0a38708238467c33ba370c58b2), [commit 552955e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/552955ed7fcbc3706f2d6192487df2fb8f3283c8) (01 Oct 2020), and [commit 349cff7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/349cff76de7fdb3b44c7018474134566a7a4ee19) (29 Sep 2020) by [Sean Barag (`sjbarag`)](https://github.com/sjbarag).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 40696c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40696c67274305d6258539de5a36649cf833f712), 27 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de9ed3ef3740f8227cc924e845032954d1f1b1b7): allow configurable default for `-o`/`--origin`
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Andrei Rybak</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sean Barag</sup>

> While the default remote name of "`origin`" can be changed at clone-time with [`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de9ed3ef3740f8227cc924e845032954d1f1b1b7/Documentation/git-clone.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup>'s `--origin` option, it was previously not possible to specify a default value for the name of that remote.
> Add support for a new `clone.defaultRemoteName` config, with the newly-created remote name resolved in priority order:
>
> 1. (Highest priority) A remote name passed directly to [`git clone -o`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de9ed3ef3740f8227cc924e845032954d1f1b1b7/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L184)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--oltnamegt))</sup>
> 2. A `clone.defaultRemoteName=new_name` in config [`git clone -c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de9ed3ef3740f8227cc924e845032954d1f1b1b7/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L209)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--cltkeygtltvaluegt))</sup>
> 3. A `clone.defaultRemoteName` value set in `/path/to/template/config`, where `--template=/path/to/template` is provided
> 4. A `clone.defaultRemoteName` value set in a non-template config file
> 5. The default value of `origin`

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de9ed3ef3740f8227cc924e845032954d1f1b1b7/Documentation/config/clone.txt#L1-L4):

> ### `clone.defaultRemoteName`
>
> The name of the remote to create when cloning a repository.
> Defaults to `origin`, and can be overridden by passing the `--origin` command-line
> option to [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de9ed3ef3740f8227cc924e845032954d1f1b1b7/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L186-L188):

> Instead of using the remote name `origin` to keep track of the upstream
> repository, use `<name>`.
> Overrides `clone.defaultRemoteName` from the config.

---

Warning:

[`git -c core.bare=false clone --bare ...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3099d4faa3ffb888cddb3b1fbba8f13a52f6726c/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L152)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---bare))</sup> would have segfaulted, which has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit 7555567](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75555676ad3908b0f847a9ae154c35e12114c82f) (10 Mar 2021) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3099d4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3099d4faa3ffb888cddb3b1fbba8f13a52f6726c), 22 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/init-db`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75555676ad3908b0f847a9ae154c35e12114c82f): handle bare clones when core.bare set to false
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Joseph Vusich</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> In [552955e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/552955ed7fcbc3706f2d6192487df2fb8f3283c8) ("`clone`: use more conventional config/option layering", 2020-10-01, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40696c67274305d6258539de5a36649cf833f712) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9b6481aedae587b1380736fb8f21785119aeb48)), `clone` learned to read configuration options earlier in its execution, before creating the new repository.
>
> However, that led to a problem: **if the `core.bare` setting is set to `false` in the global config, cloning a bare repository segfaults**.
>
> This happens because the repository is falsely thought to be non-bare, but clone has set the work tree to `NULL`, which is then dereferenced.
>
> The code to initialize the repository already considers the fact that a user might want to override the `--bare` option for [`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/75555676ad3908b0f847a9ae154c35e12114c82f/Documentation/git-init.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup>, but it doesn't take into account clone, which uses a different option.
> Let's just check that the work tree is not `NULL`, since that's how clone indicates that the repository is bare.
> This is also the case for `git init`, so we won't be regressing that case.