# Retrieve git_main_branch in Neovim

Tags: git, vim-plugin, neovim, vim-fugitive

So I have been getting very acquainted with Neovim/Spacevim lately, and it's freakin awesome!

I am in the process of setting up some personal keybindings and commands and what have you, and am currently working on Git stuff.

Coming from using VSCode and iTerm2, when wanting to switch from any branch to `master` or `main` or whatever the *main* branch is, I have an alias as follows:

```sh
alias gcom=git checkout $(git_main_branch)
```

Where I can just type `gcom` into the terminal, and it will automatically switch to whatever the *main* branch is. Unfortunately in Neovim, `git_main_branch` is not a thing, so I am trying to figure out an equivalent, where I can do something like type `:Gcom` into the Neovim command prompt, and it switches to the main branch.

I tried to set up a function like this in my `init.vim` file (*I have `coc` and all corresponding Git plugins installed, including `fugitive`*):

```
function! GitCheckoutMain()
  let gitMainBranch = system('git_main_branch')

  execute "normal! :Git checkout" . gitMainBranch
endfunction
```

and then setting up a command like

```
command! Gcom :call GitCheckoutMain()
```

But that does not do the trick. Does anyone know how I might accomplish this with Neovim? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think I actually may have figured out how to solve this. I changed my `GitCheckoutMain` function from my initial post to be as follows:

```
function GitCheckoutMain()
  let mainGitBranch = system('git branch | grep -o -m1 "\b\(master\|main\)\b"')

  echo mainGitBranch
endfunction
```

and I bound that to my `Gcom` command from above, and when I run `:Gcom` from the Neovim terminal, it prints out `master` in the case of a repo where `master` is the *main* branch. Will also test this in a repo where the main branch is `main`, but I think this will do what I want...

**EDIT**: This does in fact work! Here is my full code, for anyone interested.

```
function GitCheckoutMain()
  let mainGitBranch = system('git branch | grep -o -m1 "\b\(master\|main\)\b"')

  execute "normal! :Git checkout " . mainGitBranch
endfunction

...

command! Gcom :call GitCheckoutMain()
```

and whichever branch I am on, if I type in `:Gcom` to the Neovim terminal, it will change branches to `master` or `main` or whatever *main* branch is set up in that particular repository. Woohoo!

I want to credit the answer posted by @dwelle in this thread - [How to get the default for the master branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703168/how-to-get-the-default-for-the-master-branch-in-git) - for getting me to the end result!

Answer (score 0):

That's a nifty solution! Just wanted to add my own 2 cents about this. If you use GitHub as your repository, and you have the GitHub CLI installed, you could get the main target branch by typing

```sh
gh repo view --json defaultBranchRef --jq '.defaultBranchRef.name'
```

That will open up another mode which will list the name of the main branch. I know you already got to where you needed, but this might be another *cleaner* method you could implement.

Comment: This is a really nice way to go about it as well, and yes, much cleaner! So I tried both methods, and this method seems to be noticeably slower than what I currently have. But it's always good to know multiple ways of solving something. Thanks!!